# How to implement breakpoint functionality in a embedding of Python

Tags: python, python-c-api

I am using Python C Api to embed a python in our application. Currently when users execute their scripts, we call `PyRun_SimpleString()`. Which runs fine.

I would like to extend this functionality to allow users to run scripts in "Debug" mode, where like in a typical IDE, they would be allowed to set breakpointsm "watches", and generally step through their script.

I've looked at the API specs, googled for similar functionality, but did not find anything that would help much.

I did play with `PyEval_SetTrace()` which returns all the information I need, however, we execute the Python on the same thread as our main application and I have not found a way to "pause" python execution when the trace callback hits a line number that contains a user checked break point - and resuming the execution at a later point.

I also see that there are various "Frame" functions like `PyEval_EvalFrame()` but not a whole lot of places that demo the proper usage. Perhaps these are the functions that I should be using?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PyEval_SetTrace()` is exactly the API that you need to use. Not sure why you need some additional way to "pause" the execution; when your callback has been called, the execution is already paused and will not resume until you return from the callback.

Comment: Seems you are right, thanks! My problem was the thread I was executing the python was not the best to leave trace running. After re-factoring, all's fine.